# Wordpress Resize Image and show as thumb in post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have set crop in functions.php to resize Images for Posts.

Codex from Wordpress: [add_image_size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size), [post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)

```
  add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
  set_post_thumbnail_size(100, 100, true); //size of thumbs
  add_image_size( 'post-thumb', 180, 180, true ); //(cropped)
```

Usage is like below

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumb' ); } ?>
```

But it will not resize the thumb and shows the original size. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress will only resize images on upload, you can use [this plugin](http://austinmatzko.com/wordpress-plugins/filosofo-custom-image-sizes/) to resize images on the fly, so the first time you call an image size that does not exists, this plugin will resize the image so the next times image size will exist.

Comment: The Plugin did not solve it. I have activated the Plugin and added as described `wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'post-thumb');` to my loop.php file.